# How to disable form authentication on IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I had form authentication on my website.
It was on a web farm server and I had a directory on my website to write some log files.
I used password protection on the pleask to protect my directory and it worked fine.
When user want to see contents of that directory, they must have entered a username and password.

Last week I moved my site to a dedicated server and now I want to enable that feature again.

```
in iis7>mysite>mydirectory>authentication
```

but I cannot disable form authentication why?

I removed

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain=".mysite.com" loginUrl="Login" timeout="50" 
    requireSSL="false"   path="/"  />
```

In web.config I can disable authentication feature in iis and enable basic authentication and everything work good.

But now how can I handle it without removing my codes?
How did it worked when I was on plesk hosting panel?
I want users to enter a username and password to view a file on my folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that shows how you **Enable Forms Authentication (IIS 7)**
Maybe [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) helps you...